# How to make a dynamic type callable (react custom hook)

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typeguards, type-narrowing

Supposed I have a custom hook that returns 3 things in an array

```
export const useInput = (store: string) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(store);

  const bind = {
    value,
    onChange: (e: InputChangeEvent) => {
      setValue(e.target.value)
    }
  } 

  const reset = () => {
    setValue(store)
  }

  return [value, bind, reset]
}
```

and using it in a component

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [name, bindName, resetName] = useInput('')
  const [email, bindEmail, resetEmail] = useInput('')
  const [confirmEmail, bindConfirmEmail, resetConfirmEmail] = useInput('')

  const onSubmitHandler = (e: FormSubmitEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(`${name} ${email} ${confirmEmail}`)
    resetName();
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
        <div className={styles.modalTitle}>
          {homeText.action}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.textInputContainer}>
          <input type="text" placeholder={homeText.plName} {...bindName}/>
          <ErrorMessage message={'sad'}/>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.textInputContainer}>
          <input type="email" placeholder={homeText.plEmail} {...bindEmail}/>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.textInputContainer}>
          <input type="email" placeholder={homeText.plConfirm} {...bindConfirmEmail}/>
        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Now `resetName()` or any of the resets are uncallable cause there are 3 types there that 1 of them made sense that it shouldn't be callable like a `string`, how do I change `useInput`'s return type such that I'm able call the stuff that are callable `() => void`.

the exact thing ts doesn't want when calling `resetName()` is this
`This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'string | { value: string; onChange: (e: InputChangeEvent) => void; } | (() => void)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures.`

A solution on top of my head would be manipulating the type and narrowing it to a single type just before I execute something callable? any more ideas?

**Update**

So is it a good idea to do type assertions? I was able to make it work by asserting (`as`) `(() => void)` for now.

```
const newResetName = resetName as (() => void)
newResetName()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue here is that the return type of `useInput` is an array of items whose type as the intersection of the 3 values you return in `return [value, bind, reset]`, rather than what you need which is a tuple.

You can use `as const` to ask typescript to treat the array value as an immutable tuple instead, which will change the return type of `useInput` to a tuple:

```
return [value, bind, reset] as const
```